How do I decompose this faction into partial fractions?
Here is the fraction:
$$\frac{1}{(ar+1)(ar+a+1)}$$
I looked at the mark scheme, and it says the answer is:
$$\frac{1}{a}(\frac{1}{ar+1}-\frac{1}{ar+a+1})$$
but when I tried it I got:
$$\frac{1}{ar+1}-\frac{1}{ar+a+1}$$
How should I do this correctly?
Edit:
My method:
$$\frac{1}{(ar+1)(ar+a+1)}=\frac{A}{ar+1}+\frac{B}{ar+a+1}$$
$$1 = A(ar+a+1) + B(ar+1)$$
I tried to use a = 1 and r = -1 to get rid of B, and I found A to be 1.
Then I used a = 1 and r = 1 to find that B = -1. I don't understand where 1/a comes from though.

Just add the two fractions of your result again: $\frac{1}{ar+1}-\frac{1}{ar+a+1} = \frac{???}{(ar+1)(ar+a+1)}$ –  Do you get the original expression or not?

It's easy to check that their answer is correct and yours is wrong.  We can't say what your mistake was unless you tell us how you arrived at your answer.

@MartinR I'm aware that my answer is wrong, but I don't understand where the 1/a comes from (I've edited my question to include my process)

Because you set $a=1, \frac{1}{a}=1$ and you result is the same as the answer. Solve it without assuming a partucular value of $a$

You did everything correctly on your partial fractions,  but you want $r=0$ and $r=1$ to eliminate $r$.
If $r=0$, you'll get $$1 = A(a+1) + B(1) \implies 1 = Aa + A + B \implies B = 1-Aa-A$$
If $r=1$, you'll get $$1 = A(2a+1) + B(a+1) \implies 1=2aA+A +(1-Aa +A)(a+1) \implies a(1-aA)=0$$ so either $a=0$ or $1-aA = 0$; $a=0$ is not a solution, which means $A = \dfrac {1}{a}$ and thus $B=-\dfrac {1}{a}.$
Factor out $\dfrac {1}{a}$ and you're done.

Why $$A(ar+a+1)+B(ar+1)=(ar+a+1)(ar+1)$$? If we multiply both sides by $$(ar+a+1)(ar+1)$$, wouldn't we get $$A(ar+a+1)+B(ar+1)=1$$?
I did try to use a=1 and r=-1 to get rid of B, and I found A to be 1. Then I used a = 1 and r = 1 to find that B = -1. I don't understand where 1/a comes from though

@Boris Kaptsanov: I've corrected my post.  I didn't realize you had solved it the way I did, but when I went over it again, I found that I needed $r=0$ and $r=1$ to get the equations you need.

Ohhh, that makes sense - just to check, my answer was wrong because I picked values for both a and r, when I should've just picked values for r?

@BorisKaptsanov Yes - the goal is to get simultaneous equations in $A$ and $B$ to solve.  Luckily with $r=0$, I was able to substitute that result into $r=1$, and that's when the "aha!" moment came in.

To expand on my comment:
because you set $a=1 \implies \frac{1}{a}=1$ and you result is the same as the answer. Solve it without assuming a partucular value of $a$:
$$1 = A(ar+a+1) + B(ar+1)$$
Set $ar+1=0 \implies 1=Aa \implies A=\frac{1}{a}$ 
Set $ar+a+1=0 \implies ar+1=-a, 1=-Ba \implies B=-\frac{1}{a}$
